# Mount multiple remote directories into on linux

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs

I'm trying to mount multiple directories from X different servers, into a single server, and im trying to do it using SSHFS.

this is what im trying:

`sshfs root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/usr/... /home/ABC`

then when i try to add another one
`sshfs root@zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz:/usr/... /home/ABC`
im getting :

**fuse: mountpoint is not empty

fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option**

is there a way to mount multiple remote directories into a single directory?
Should I use something different?